# I have some problems with the XML layouts (android development).

Tags: android, xml

I think I have some problems with a LinearLayout container. I do not know how to fix these problems:

I am a beginner to XML but I think the problem is in the second LinearLayout. I hope someone can help me out.

The code is here below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
    **<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        andriod:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>**
        <Button 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"         

            />





</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You didnt describe your problem at all...

Comment: We need to know how you wanted it layed out (preferably an image) and how it was instead (as a screen shot preferably). I know you can't post images yet so just link to them

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see when reading your xml file is that inside the main `LinearLayout` you have 3 elements with the properties about the width and height as follows:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

which means you expect the elements to fill entirely the main `LinearLayout`. This is not going to work. A linear layout has ordered not overlapping elements (`RelativeLayout` is there for that). Since the main `LinearLayout` is supposed to be oriented vertically, I suppose that for these three elements, you need to set the properties to match the whole width of main `LinearLayout` and to be wrapped vertically, by setting these values:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

You should apply these to the `TextView`, `LinearLayout` and `Button` elements of second level.

Answer (score 0):

If you have overlapping imageviews try adding weights to them and/or changing the width to not match the parent and only wrapping the content.

Answer (score 0):

please change andriod to android    ( Line 14 )

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code has a typo. Your fix might be as simple as replacing the line:

`andriod:orientation="horizontal"`

with:

`android:orientation="horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the image you posted, I think you may have forgotten to add weights to occupy the free space in your Linearlayouts. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        andriod:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
        <Button 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"         
            />    

</LinearLayout>
```